# NullReferenceException where only variables are structs

Tags: c#, .net

I'm consistently getting a very confusing exception for 2 users from the same code that runs fine for about 250 others.

It's a `NullReferenceException` in a `CompareTo` method while doing a sort.  The top of the callstack is:

```
at MyApp.Database.IndexablePropertyValue.CompareTo(IndexablePropertyValue other)
at MyApp.Database.IndexablePropertyValue.CompareTo(Object obj)
```

The `CompareTo` methods from `IndexablePropertyValue` are

```
public int CompareTo(IndexablePropertyValue other)
{
    int result = m_propertyId.CompareTo(other.m_propertyId);
    if(result != 0)
        return result;
    return m_dropDownValueId.CompareTo(other.m_dropDownValueId);
}

public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    if(obj == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
    return CompareTo((IndexablePropertyValue)obj);
}
```

The `ArgumentNullException` is never thrown.  The confusing part is that `IndexablePropertyValue` and the type used for the `m_propertyId` & `m_dropDownValueId` values (`Suid`) are both structs.

As the exception is produced from an optimized build it's possible the `CompareTo` method from the `Suid` struct has been inlined, so here's the `CompareTo` method in the `Suid` struct:

```
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        Suid other = (Suid)obj;
        int result = s.CompareTo(other.s);
        if(result != 0)
            return result;
        return d.CompareTo(other.d);
    }
```

Variables `s` and `d` are mutable `Int32` fields of the struct.  (Making them immutable would of course be better, but some of our serialization code doesn't support it.)

And signatures for the structs:

```
public struct IndexablePropertyValue : IComparable<IndexablePropertyValue>, IComparable
public struct Suid : IComparable, IEquatable<Suid>
```

I don't understand how a `NullReferenceException` is even possible from the `CompareTo` method.  Hopefully someone will have an idea on how it's possible.  A bug in a particular framework version perhaps?  We're targeting 4.5.

Comment: Show us the `CompareTo` method of `Suid`. Assuming this is an optimized build, it could very well have thrown in there, but the method could inlined.

Comment: Thanks, I've included that too.  That is also only using value types however.

Comment: I don't understand how NRE would be possible either. But I'm extremely doubtful that there's a bug in the framework. Errors affecting a tiny proportion of users who are using the program in the same way often turn out to be some kind of threading issue, but even that wouldn't seem to explain this here (the posted code doesn't seem to have any opportunities for thread race conditions). I'm left wondering if you're absolutely sure that all of your users are running the same version of the code; is it possible these two users have some older code where an NRE is actually possible?

Comment: Was `obj` null? Add a runtime assert.

Comment: @Peter Yes it's the same code, and I'm pretty sure it's not a threading issue as the behaviour is consistent on each machine and there is synchronization code handling that.  @usr The assert in `IndexablePropertyValue` never gets hit.  I'll add an assert for `Suid` too.  A quick test shows that casting a null object ref to a struct does cause a NRE - not the exception I was expecting, but that might be where it is thrown.  Not sure how, if the only candidate is a boxed struct.